# Compare Values From 2 While Loops (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create all time standings for head to head matchups in a fantasy football league. I'm using two separate queries and grabbing the data with two separate while loops. I was hoping I could compare the two with an IF statement, but no-go.

My queries are as follows:

```
$query5 = "SELECT *, SUM(POINTS) ";
    $query5 .= " FROM SCHEDULE";
    $query5 .= " WHERE owner = 'DUSTIN'";
    $query5 .= " AND OPPONENT = 'LEE'";
    $query5 .= " GROUP BY WEEK ";
    $result5 = mysqli_query($con, $query5);

    $query6 = "SELECT *, SUM(POINTS) ";
    $query6 .= " FROM SCHEDULE";
    $query6 .= " WHERE owner = 'LEE'";
    $query6 .= " AND OPPONENT = 'DUSTIN'";
    $query6 .= " GROUP BY WEEK ";
    $result6 = mysqli_query($con, $query6);
```

My PHP:

```
while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5)){$row5 ["SUM(POINTS)"];
while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6)){$row6 ["SUM(POINTS)"];  
if ( $row5 ["SUM(POINTS)"] > $row6 ["SUM(POINTS)"] ){
$win++;
}
else {
$loss++;
}
}
}
```

The function works for $row6, but for $row5 it's grabbing the same number over and over rather than cycling through the array.

Here is sample data:

```
YEAR    WEEK    OWNER   OPPONENT    POSITION    PLAYER  POINTS
2008    1   Dustin  Brandon RB  Chris Johnson, Ten RB   19.7
2008    1   Dustin  Brandon QB  Ben Roethlisberger, Pit QB  13.1
2008    1   DUSTIN  BRANDON D/ST    Titans D/ST, Ten D/ST   17
2008    1   DUSTIN  BRANDON WR  Roddy White, Atl WR 5.4
2008    1   DUSTIN  BRANDON RB  Laurence Maroney, NE RB 6.1
2008    1   BRANDON DUSTIN  RB  Adrian Peterson, Min RB 21.4
2008    1   BRANDON DUSTIN  RB  Edgerrin James, Ari RB  15
2008    1   BRANDON DUSTIN  WR  Larry Fitzgerald, Ari WR    9.1
2008    1   BRANDON DUSTIN  k   Joe Nedney, SF K    4.5
2008    1   BRANDON DUSTIN  WR  Chris Chambers, SD WR   11.4
```

I need to add up total points for Dustin in week 1 and compare them to total points for Brandon in week 1. And indicate a win for the winning team.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this entirely in SQL, but I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will return the total # of wins for dustin, lee, and the total # of ties. Where a win is defined by scoring more points than your opponent in the same week.

The query assumes that both players have at least some points for every week. If this isn't the case you'll have to convert from an inner join to a full join.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.points > t2.points THEN 1 END) dustin_win_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.points > t1.points THEN 1 END) lee_win_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.points = t1.points THEN 1 END) tie_count
FROM
    (SELECT WEEK, SUM(POINTS) points
    FROM SCHEDULE WHERE
    OWNER = 'DUSTIN'
    AND OPPONENT = 'LEE'
    GROUP BY WEEK) t1
    JOIN (SELECT WEEK, SUM(POINTS) points
    FROM SCHEDULE WHERE
    OWNER = 'LEE'
    AND OPPONENT = 'DUSTIN'
    GROUP BY WEEK) t2 ON t1.WEEK = t2.WEEK
```

Comment: This works perfect when I run the SQL - thanks! I'm getting a query error when I try implementing it to PHP, but I'll work through it.

Comment: How would I display the results using PHP/HTML?

Comment: @user3787390 You'll have to fetch the row using `mysqli_query` and display using `print $row['dustin_win_count']` etc. if you need more help pls open a new question

Comment: Damn, those are some kick ass Query skills you got there Fuzzy Tree. upvoted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real sharp on the ins and outs of complex mysql queries, but this is similar to what i use to calculate votes in a voting system i've been designing.

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(POINTS)(CASE WHEN owner = 'DUSTIN' AND opponent = 'LEE' THEN 1 END) dustin, 
SUM(POINTS)(CASE WHEN owner = 'LEE' AND opponent = 'DUSTIN' THEN 1 END)lee, FROM SCHEDULE GROUP BY WEEK;";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if($row['dustin'] > $row['lee'])
    {
        $win++;
    }else{
        $loss++;
    }
}
```

It may not work for your situation since i use it with `COUNT` instead of SUM, but it might work. if it doesn't let me know and i'll try something else.